# DFP & Google Analytics: Is there way to trace google analytics page views that came from DFP ads?

Tags: google-analytics, google-dfp

Was there a way to track google analytics view that is from DFP ads?

Comment: Do you control the ad creatives? You could just append something to the link?

Comment: yes @MattCooper we have the ad creative control. what do we need to add in the link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright. I just found a tool for this:

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033867?hl=en&ref_topic=1032998

Thanks!